# How Do I set drop down menu list open when I click on parent li Then open the sub li using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This code I post is an image, Html and css code..
Any one tell me How Do I set Drop down menu list when I click on parent `<li>`Then open the sub `<li>` using `javascript`?
In this image see its look of code.

```js
<script>
$(".menu  li a").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();
        });
  $("#menu1 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  }); 
  $("#menu2 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  });
    
 </script>
```

```css
#leftcolsearch {
 float: left;
 width: 210px;
 margin: 0 7px 10px 0;
}
#leftcolsearch .option {
 float: left;
 width: 196px;
 border: #CCCCCC dotted 1px;
 border-top: none;
 padding: 1px 0 10px 10px;
}
.menu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}

.menu li {list-style: none; float:left; width:185px; margin:0;}
.menu li ul{ margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:8px; display:none; }
.menu li ul li{
margin:4px 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 100%;
display: inline;
}
.menu li a.active,.menu li a:hover{
 color: #539dbc;
 background: url(../images/checkboxwc.png) no-repeat left top; display:block;
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.menu a {
 color: #999;
 background: url(../images/checkbox.png) no-repeat left top;
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftcolsearch"> 
  <div class="option">
    <h4 style="margin-left:7">Date:</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
      <li><a href="">2013</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2014</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">January</a></li>
          <li><a href="">February</a></li>
          <li><a href="">March</a></li>
          <li><a href="">April</a></li>
          <li><a href="">May</a></li>
          <li><a href="">June</a></li>
          <li><a href="">July</a></li>
          <li><a href="">August</a></li>
          <li><a href="">September</a></li>
          <li><a href="">October</a></li>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div class="option">
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
      <li><a href="">Africa</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Algeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Angola</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cameroon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Egypt</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kenya</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Madagascar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Morocco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mozambique</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Nigeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> South Africa</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Tanzania, United Republic Of</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Asia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Bahrain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bangladesh</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Canada</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hong Kong</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> India</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Indonesia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Iran, Islamic Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Israel</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Japan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Jordan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kazakhstan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Korea, Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lebanon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Macao</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Malaysia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Oman</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Pakistan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Philippines</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Qatar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Saudi Arabia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Singapore</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sri Lanka</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Taiwan, Province Of China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Thailand</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Arab Emirates</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Vietnam</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> Australia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Fiji</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> New Zealand</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Europe</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Austria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Belgium</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bulgaria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Croatia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Czech Republic</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Denmark</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Estonia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Finland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Germany</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Greece</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hungary</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ireland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Italy</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lithuania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Monaco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Netherlands</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Norway</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Poland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Portugal</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Romania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Russian Federation</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Serbia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovakia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovenia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Spain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sweden</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Switzerland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ukraine</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Kingdom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">North America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Canada
            Costa Rica</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cuba</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United States</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">South America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Brazil</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Chile</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Colombia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Peru</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Uruguay</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  

  $("#menu  li").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();

        });
```

for class

```
$(".menu  li").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();

        });
```

Comment: where this code I write ans set .tell me Qaisar                                                                                                                                                                                            jQuery("#menu  li").click(function(){ 
jQuery(this).next("ul").toggle();

    });

Comment: in you file <head></head> tag

Comment: i already try this code method but not work...only this code work on date potion but when i click  Location potion <li> not open the sub list..

Comment: change the id for second ul like menu to menu1 and repeat code for id men1 too. it is work for only id..

Comment: but not any other option only one time write this code and apply all the menu...because i use 4 menu .and apply same css code on 4 menu.

Comment: use css on class it will easy for you and change the id's

Comment: i Chang the code in class.and Chang the id menu1,menu2 like this .but not work.not open sub <li>.and Now Date potion is not open .

Comment: have you add 
$("#menu1  li").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();

        }); 
$("#menu2  li").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();

        }); 
for every id?

Comment: for other you are clicking on  $("#menu1 li a").click(function(){ $(this).next("ul").toggle(); });  because you are clicking on a tag

Comment: I add this code but not work.. <script>
$(".menu  li a").click(function(){ 
    $(this).next("ul").toggle();

        });
  $("#menu1 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  }); 
  $("#menu2 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  });
  $("#menu3 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  }); 
  $("#menu4 li a").click(function(){ 
  $(this).next("ul").toggle(); 
  });  
 </script>

Comment: <script> $("#menu1 li a").click(function(){ $(this).next("ul").toggle(); }); </script> place this code and place in you footer area

Comment: yes its work..thanks..but very speedily open ...how i can handle the speed?

Comment: i used check box image not check box...when i click on <li> or select then not show the tick mark image...how can i handle this?/

Comment: i add this code but now sub <li> menu list not open..action performed but not open the menu.

Comment: add your question on stack and your code then i will check and kindly comment link here so i can check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160761/i-add-this-code-but-now-sub-li-menu-list-not-open-action-performed-but-not-op

Comment: answer it kindly check and feedback me if it is solve your problem