# i add this code but now sub <li> menu list not open..action performed but not open the menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This code I post is an image, Html and css code.. when i click on check box image but not open sub `<li>`. 
if i write the code this.

```
$("#menu1 li a").click(function(){$(this).next("ul").toggle(); });
```

but sub `<li>` open very fast.any one tell me?? 
In this image see its look of code.
[image]

```js
<script>
 $("#menu1 li a").click(function(){  
$(this).next("ul").toggle("slow"); }); 
$("#menu2 li a").click(function(){  
$(this).next("ul").toggle("slow"); }); 
</script>
```

```css
#leftcolsearch {
 float: left;
 width: 210px;
 margin: 0 7px 10px 0;
}
#leftcolsearch .option {
 float: left;
 width: 196px;
 border: #CCCCCC dotted 1px;
 border-top: none;
 padding: 1px 0 10px 10px;
}
.menu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}

.menu li {list-style: none; float:left; width:185px; margin:0;}
.menu li ul{ margin:0; padding:0; margin-left:8px; display:none; }
.menu li ul li{
margin:4px 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 100%;
display: inline;
}
.menu a {
 color: #999;
 background: url(../images/checkbox.png) no-repeat left top;
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
}
.menu li a.active,.menu li a:hover{
 color: #539dbc;
background: url(../images/checkboxwc.png) no-repeat left top; display:block; 
 padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftcolsearch"> 
  <div class="option">
    <h4 style="margin-left:7">Date:</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
      <li><a href="">2013</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">2014</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">January</a></li>
          <li><a href="">February</a></li>
          <li><a href="">March</a></li>
          <li><a href="">April</a></li>
          <li><a href="">May</a></li>
          <li><a href="">June</a></li>
          <li><a href="">July</a></li>
          <li><a href="">August</a></li>
          <li><a href="">September</a></li>
          <li><a href="">October</a></li>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div class="option">
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
      <li><a href="">Africa</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Algeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Angola</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cameroon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Egypt</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kenya</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Madagascar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Morocco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mozambique</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Nigeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> South Africa</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Tanzania, United Republic Of</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Asia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Bahrain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bangladesh</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Canada</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hong Kong</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> India</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Indonesia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Iran, Islamic Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Israel</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Japan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Jordan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kazakhstan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Korea, Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lebanon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Macao</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Malaysia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Oman</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Pakistan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Philippines</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Qatar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Saudi Arabia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Singapore</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sri Lanka</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Taiwan, Province Of China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Thailand</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Arab Emirates</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Vietnam</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href=""> Australia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Fiji</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> New Zealand</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Europe</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Austria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Belgium</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bulgaria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Croatia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Czech Republic</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Denmark</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Estonia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Finland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Germany</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Greece</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hungary</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ireland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Italy</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lithuania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Monaco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Netherlands</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Norway</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Poland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Portugal</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Romania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Russian Federation</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Serbia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovakia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovenia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Spain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sweden</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Switzerland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ukraine</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Kingdom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">North America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Canada
            Costa Rica</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cuba</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United States</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">South America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Brazil</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Chile</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Colombia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Peru</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Uruguay</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r8nfvn8u/1/ - what do you mean

Comment: also try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r8nfvn8u/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny nice job! However i did not undertand what exactly is her issue!

Comment: @Wishy even me.. Just posted the code to show it works... only 1 issue is not preventing the default action of the anchor click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user **javascript:void(0)** in **href** the page is loading there is no issue with javascript now check it...

```
<div id="leftcolsearch"> 
  <div class="option">
    <h4 style="margin-left:7">Date:</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">2013</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">2014</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">January</a></li>
          <li><a href="">February</a></li>
          <li><a href="">March</a></li>
          <li><a href="">April</a></li>
          <li><a href="">May</a></li>
          <li><a href="">June</a></li>
          <li><a href="">July</a></li>
          <li><a href="">August</a></li>
          <li><a href="">September</a></li>
          <li><a href="">October</a></li>
          <li><a href="">November</a></li>
          <li><a href="">December</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div class="option">
    <h4>Location</h4>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Africa</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Algeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Angola</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cameroon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Egypt</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kenya</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Madagascar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Morocco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mozambique</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Nigeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> South Africa</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Tanzania, United Republic Of</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">Asia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Bahrain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bangladesh</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Canada</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hong Kong</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> India</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Indonesia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Iran, Islamic Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Israel</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Japan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Jordan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Kazakhstan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Korea, Republic Of</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lebanon</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Macao</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Malaysia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Oman</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Pakistan</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Philippines</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Qatar</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Saudi Arabia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Singapore</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sri Lanka</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Taiwan, Province Of China</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Thailand</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Arab Emirates</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Vietnam</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Australia</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Fiji</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> New Zealand</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">Europe</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Austria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Belgium</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Bulgaria</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Croatia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Czech Republic</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Denmark</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Estonia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Finland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Germany</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Greece</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Hungary</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ireland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Italy</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Lithuania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Monaco</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Netherlands</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Norway</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Poland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Portugal</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Romania</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Russian Federation</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Serbia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovakia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Slovenia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Spain</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Sweden</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Switzerland</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Ukraine</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United Kingdom</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="javascript:void(0)">North America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Canada
            Costa Rica</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Cuba</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> United States</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">South America</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Brazil</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Chile</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Colombia</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Peru</a></li>
          <li><a href=""> Uruguay</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for help..i add this code..but now when i click on <li> open sub <li> menu.but when i again click on open <li> for close to sub <li> then not close sub <li> ..

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)">Asia</a> first click open the submenu again click on that close it if you want like open one <ul></ul> time then have to modify the script too tell me what you want exactly

Comment: now this code work...but only first Date menu i click menu open.and sub menu list also open but at the same time  again this sub menu list show in front of sub menu list.Two time this list show.only first Date menu i found this issue..

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)">2014</a> when you click on that the submenu is showing. next what you want? i don't understand.

Comment: now i add the image you see ..when i click on 2014 then open the sub <li>..but two time show the sub list.why..only i issue i show on Date menu..

Comment: it is not open fast it is reloading the page becasue of <a href=""> replace it <a href="#"> it will not load the page..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77486/discussion-between-samia-naveed-and-qaisar-satti).

Answer (score 1):

Same Html

```
<div id="leftcolsearch"> 
    <div class="option">
        <h4 style="margin-left:7">Date:</h4>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu1">
            <li><a href="">2013</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">November</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">December</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">2014</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">January</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">February</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">March</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">April</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">May</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">June</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">July</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">August</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">September</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">October</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">November</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">December</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="option">
        <h4>Location</h4>
        <ul class="menu" id="menu2">
            <li><a href="">Africa</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Algeria</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Angola</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Cameroon</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Egypt</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Kenya</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Madagascar</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Morocco</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Mozambique</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Nigeria</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> South Africa</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Tanzania, United Republic Of</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="">Asia</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Bahrain</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Bangladesh</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Canada</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> China</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Hong Kong</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> India</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Indonesia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Iran, Islamic Republic Of</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Israel</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Japan</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Jordan</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Kazakhstan</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Korea, Republic Of</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Lebanon</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Macao</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Malaysia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Oman</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Pakistan</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Philippines</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Qatar</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Saudi Arabia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Singapore</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Sri Lanka</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Taiwan, Province Of China</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Thailand</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> United Arab Emirates</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Vietnam</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href=""> Australia</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Australia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Fiji</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> New Zealand</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="">Europe</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Austria</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Belgium</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Bulgaria</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Croatia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Czech Republic</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Denmark</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Estonia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Finland</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> France</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Germany</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Greece</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Hungary</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Ireland</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Italy</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Lithuania</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Monaco</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Netherlands</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Norway</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Poland</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Portugal</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Romania</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Russian Federation</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Serbia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Slovakia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Slovenia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Spain</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Sweden</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Switzerland</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Turkey</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Ukraine</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> United Kingdom</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="">North America</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Canada
                        Costa Rica</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Cuba</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> United States</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="">South America</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Argentina</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Brazil</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Chile</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Colombia</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Mexico</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Peru</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""> Uruguay</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Same Css

```
#leftcolsearch {
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
    margin: 0 7px 10px 0;
}
#leftcolsearch .option {
    float: left;
    width: 196px;
    border: #CCCCCC dotted 1px;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 1px 0 10px 10px;
}
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 2px;
}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    width:185px;
    margin:0;
}
.menu li ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:8px;
    display:none;
}
.menu li ul li {
    margin:4px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 100%;
    display: inline;
}
.menu a {
    color: #999;
    background: url(../images/checkbox.png) no-repeat left top;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.menu li a.active, .menu li a:hover {
    color: #539dbc;
    background: url(../images/checkboxwc.png) no-repeat left top;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

In Jquery You can use in such a way that you can use preventDefault()

```
$("#menu1 li a").click(function (e) {
    $(this).next("ul").toggle("slow");
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#menu2 li a").click(function (a) {
    $(this).next("ul").toggle("slow");
    a.preventDefault();
});
```

[Try This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7L7qpmk3/)